# Compilation error using SafeMath

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, openzeppelin-contracts, safemath

I am trying to do subtraction operation using the SafeMath library. The following is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
library SafeMath {
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }
}
contract Underflow1 {
using SafeMath for uint;
    uint8 num= 0;
    function testf2() public returns (uint8){
    //val--;    
    num= num.sub(1);
    return num;
    }
}
```

I am getting following error message:

> browser/UF8-SM.sol:13:10: TypeError: Member "sub" not found or not
>   visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint8. num= num.sub(1);
>   ^-----^

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because `num` is of type `uint8`, and the `sub()` function of SafeMath is looking for type `uint256`. Additionally you declare `using SafeMath for uint;`, which confirms that it only works with `uint256` (as `uint` is an alias for `uint256`).

---

There are two ways to fix it:

1) Make `num` a `uint256` type. Your code would look as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
library SafeMath {
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }
}

contract Underflow1 {
using SafeMath for uint;
    uint256 num= 0;
    function testf2() public returns (uint256){
    //val--;    
    num = num.sub(1);
    return num;
    }
}
```

2) (Not preferred) Allow SafeMath to handle type `uint8`. Your code would look as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
library SafeMath {
  function sub(uint8 a, uint8 b) internal pure returns (uint8) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }
}

contract Underflow1 {
using SafeMath for uint8;
    uint8 num= 0;
    function testf2() public returns (uint8){
    //val--;    
    num = num.sub(1);
    return num;
    }
}
```